# Laravel 5 lockscreen

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

So, I'm doing this app in Laravel and my client wants it to have a "lockscreen" after 3 minutes of inactivity, something like what new PayPal site is doing. So if you're not active for 3 minutes you are presented with lockscreen view and you have to type in your password to retrieve the session.

It would be awesome if I could achieve this without messing with core files, like via controller and new middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session) for this and check for the time use waited with each new request. You could use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) for that.

```
$request->session()->put('expire_time', \Carbon::now()->addMinutes(3));
```

Comment: Addition to that, you have to handle when user is idle and trigger your lock screen because this will work fine for new requests not idle situation.

Comment: I never saw such behavior, usually when you click some link, you get the message `session expired...`. But yes, you can handle this with JS and show message to a user in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have also applied this functionality on my app use this package.

https://github.com/orangehill/bootstrap-session-timeout

Its Awesome.

After the session times out you just on that request you break the user session and ask him to login again.